# Attempting to pass a string to a constructed function

Tags: javascript, jquery

still floundering around in my attempts to understand functions. How would I go about constructing a function with values I want to pass to it?

```
var box = $('#box1');


function pushCard(arg1) {
  if (this.style.opacity == 0.5) {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
  } 
  else {
    this.style.opacity = 0.5;
    window.alert(arg1);
  }
}

box.click(pushCard('String'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: be aware of the difference between functions / function results and when functions are passed as values / when they're called (and their result is passed)

The culprit is with this line:

```js
box.click(pushCard('String'));
```

You're calling `box.click()` with "something". JavaScript needs to evaluate expressions before passing them as function arguments.

In this case, you instruct JavaScrip to run `box.click(pushCard('String'))` = call `box.click` with value of `pushCard('String')` as first parameter.

In order to do this, JavaScript first needs to evaluate `pushCard('String')` by running `pushCard` with value `'String'` as first parameter (this doesn't need more evaluation since it's already a value).

The result of `pushCard('String')` is `undefined` (you're returning nothing from that function). So in effect, it's the equivalent of `box.click(undefined)`.

This is what you want:

```js
box.click(function() {pushCard('String')});
```

(or with ES6 arrow functions: `box.click(() => pushCard('String'));`)

In this case, you're assigning `box.click()` a function. This is what jQuery .click()` expects, a click handler which will run (be evaluated) then the click happens, not when the click handler is assigned.

In JavaScript, you can pass functions as values, and they are evaluated when explicitly **called**:

```
function test() {
   alert('I have been called');
}

function delay_it(handler) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      handler(); // ⇽ call given function
   }, 1000);
   // shorter: setTimeout(handler, 1000);
}

// Wrong (we're calling test() by ourselves and passing the result (undefined) to delay_it
delay_it(test());

// Correct (we're giving test as function to delay_it, delay_it will call the function)
delay_it(test);
```

Comment: I really appreciate the thoughtful response, this is tremendously helpful.

Comment: I have been attempting to make this work using the click methods you provided but they don't seem to work with the "this" method. However if I delete I am able to pass values to the function. Any ideas on how to make both work?